# How to Upload image in specified folder and save path in database .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task Create([Bind]Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                foreach (var Image in files)
                {
                    if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var file = Image;

                        var uploads = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads\\img");
                        if (file.Length > 0)
                        {
                            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                                employee.ImageName = fileName;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = employee.Id,name=employee.FirstName});
             }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        }
            return View(employee);

        }
```

when i save image, image save successfully in database, but it takes full image path like this `C:\Users\VIZO\Desktop\employee.jpg` i dont want like this, i need to save image path somehting like this `~images\employee.jpg` and in specific folder and same path should save in database, also if someone show me after saving correct path how i can view that image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create and save that path which can work in browser. like this

```
"uploads/img/" + fileName
```

`fileName` which you create at run time.

**Action Method Updated**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task Create([Bind]Employee employee)
    {
        string uploadPath = "uploads/img";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    var uploadPathWithfileName = Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName);

                    var uploadAbsolutePath = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, uploadPathWithfileName);

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadAbsolutePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                            employee.ImageName = uploadPathWithfileName;
                        }
                }
            }
            db.Employees.Add(employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = employee.Id, name = employee.FirstName });
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        }
        return View(employee);

    }
```

Comment: can you guide me little bit how i can do in my code above?